# Zend_Http_Client load content to iframe

Tags: zend-framework, iframe, zend-http-client

is it the same if I make Zend_Http_Client request and load the response from it to an iframe and if I do it from a form setting the iframe as a target? I set the iframe src to my controller/action and in it I have Zend_Http_Client

> $response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
>           echo  $response->getBody();

does it has difference if I do it with a form, setting up the target iframe.

i want to have this already loaded when I start the page not when I press the button submit.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the question is, but there will not be any difference with a Zend Form inside an iframe. Iframe's are their own webpages and behave as such. Populating the HTML from the response of a Zend_Http_Client request won't have any negative effect; to the browser, it's just HTML, regardless of where it came from.